# SQL Server 2008 R2: ROW_NUMBER() with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE AZTool
(
    t_ID int,
    z_ID int,
    col_date date
);
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO AZTool values(12,23409,'2017-01-02')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(12,23409,'2017-01-03')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(21,23409,'2017-03-14')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(12,24455,'2017-04-22')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(22,24455,'2017-05-13')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(22,35600,'2017-04-04')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(23,35600,'2017-05-14')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(24,35600,'2017-05-16')
INSERT INTO AZTool values(25,35600,'2017-05-24')
```

Expected output:

```
t_ID    z_ID    RowNumber
-------------------------
12      23409   1
12      23409   1
21      23409   2
12      24455   1
22      24455   2
22      35600   1
23      35600   2
24      35600   3
25      35600   4
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT
    t_ID, z_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t_ID, z_ID ORDER BY z_ID) rn
FROM 
    AZTool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems I corrected:

- Remove `t_ID` from the partition
- Order by `t_ID` in the `ORDER BY` clause
- Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT
    t_ID,
    z_ID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY z_ID ORDER BY t_ID) rn
FROM AZTool;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` Function :

```
SELECT t_ID,z_ID,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY z_ID ORDER BY t_ID) rn
FROM AZTool
```

**Result :**

[image]